# LTC to BCC transaction shows confirm but still not recieved

Tags: transactions, litecoin

I had the transfer of litecoint from coinbase to btc wallet 19days ago  but still I didn’t receive the BCC  in my wallet.

Actually I have transferred around 42 LTC to BCC and the transcation shows confirmation and went successful.

Details of the traction is below, It’s showing successful :

https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/5345f0a35f818f551131fceb51635ca3cd411aa4a74bdc12a08424ff97cf4dc6/

https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/befbdc41020df39b2be83dda52814d7242a5d0a3952d92d9bfcd4e9947f9680e/

Is there a way I can recover that back to the address from its sent.
Could you please let help me to track this.

Comment: What do you mean by "LTC to BCC transaction"? Did you send LTC to a BCC address or did you send to an exchange or swapping service (e.g. shapeshift)?

Answer (score 1):

LTC, BTC, and BCC (whatever that may be) are three different networks. When you send LTC to an address from a different network's wallet, they are received to that address on *the Litecoin network*.They don't magically turn into a different currency.

If you control the private keys corresponding to the recipient address, you may be able to recover the coins. Otherwise, you may want to get in touch with whomever controls the private keys of the recipient address and ask them if they can do you a solid.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have done this from my Coinbase account to freewallet.org BCC wallet and from last 20 days they are keep delaying to refund back . Initially they said this transaction not went through and they will refund back but still they haven’t refund back.